# Entity Framework - mudança de nome de propriedade de navegação gera erro de validação de schema (edmx)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Temos um sistema .net que utiliza o Entity Framework 6 (database first). Algumas tabelas possuem mais de uma fk para outra tabela. O entity, quando gera as propriedades de navegação para estes relacionamentos, nomeia-as com um sufixo numeral incremental.
Ex (tabelas Status e TabelaB):

**Status**

cd_status

descricao

**TabelaB**

id

nome

cd_status_inicial (FK -> Status.cd_status)

cd_status_final (FK -> Status.cd_status)

O EF6 gera a entitade referente a TabelaB, da seguinte forma:

```
public partial class TabelaB
{
  public int32 id { get; set; }
  public string nome { get; set; }
  public int32 cd_status_inicial {get; set; }
  public int32 cd_status_final {get; set; }

  public Status Status { get; set; }
  public Status Status1 { get; set; }
}
```

Os nomes das propriedades de navegação não estão com a nomenclatura que facilite o entendimento do código. Alterando o template T4 (.tt) consegui fazer com que as propriedades ficasse com nomes mais adequados:

```
public partial class TabelaB
{
  public int32 id { get; set; }
  public string nome { get; set; }
  public int32 cd_status_inicial {get; set; }
  public int32 cd_status_final {get; set; }

  public Status Status_inicial { get; set; }
  public Status Status_final { get; set; }
}
```

Ocorre que esta alteração gera erro de validação no schema do edmx, quando se vai executar alguma consulta através o entity, pois no edmx constam os nomes "Status" e "Status1", que não existe mais.

Existe alguma forma de customizar também a criação do arquivo edmx para gerar os nomes das propriedades de navegação da mesma forma que as classes das entidades?

Comment: Ao invés de renomear apenas nessa classe você precisa atualizar todas as referências, tente renomear selecionando a propriedade com dois cliques e depois segure o ctrl e tecle R duas vezes. Se isso não resolver, você precisar revisar os seus mappers

Comment: Leandro, a alteração do nome das propriedades eu fiz através do template T4 (*.tt) que o entity gera. Fiz a mudança no template para que nas próximas atualizações de banco, quando eu atualizar o edmx ("Update Model from Database), as classes já sejam geradas com novo padrão de nome. E isto funcionou. Ocorre que, quando o entity vai executar alguma consulta ele faz uma validação dos campos do edmx em relação às classes e como os nomes são diferentes ele retorna o erro. Alterando os nomes dos campo, na mão, no edmx a aplicação funciona. Estou procurando uma forma disto ser automático também.